# Angular 11 upgrade from 10 - css :host(.name) where .name is not added to the component

Tags: angular

We have an Angular 10 application which our components are structured with SCSS like:

**app-header.component.html**
`<app-header>`

**app-header.component.scss**
`:host(.header) { ... }`

**app-header.component.ts**
We are adding
`@HostBinding('class.header') true;`

When we run the application in Angular 10 it attaches the .header to the component at compilation.

`<app-header class="header">`

In our Angular 11 application we have to manually add the class="header" to the component for it to inherit the styles from the :host() {} binding.

Is there a setting in the angular.json configuration or somewhere else that will do this for us? We really don't want to go through all the components to assign the class to each implementation.

Comment: Are you saying that adding this `:host(.header) { ... }` in `.scss` file will add `.header` class to `app-header` element in `.html` file automatically?, Then you are mistaken, It is used to only style component's host element if it has class `.header`. Probably you are adding class using `@HostBinding`. Read [Special selectors](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors)

Comment: @Sameer yes, you are correct, we are adding the: @HostBinding('class.header') true; But it is not applying the hostBinding to the component in Angular 11. In Angular 10 it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. On the app-header.component.ts file you have to apply the name of the class to the variable.

**Old implementation**
`@HostBinding('class.header') true;`

**New implementation**
`@HostBinding('class.header') header = true;`